# How can I wait for data before it is available - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_isInit) {
      print('First stat');
      final restaurant = await Provider.of<Restaurants>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchAndSetRestaurants();
      print('test');
    }
    _isInit = false;

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  bool showFavourites = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
        //bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
        appBar: homeAppBar(context),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: showFavourites
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child:
                      RestaurantList(), //RestaurantList(restaurants: restaurants)
                )
              : Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                      SearchBox(
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
                      CategoryList(),
                      RestaurantList(), //RestaurantList(restaurants: restaurants)
                    ]),
        ));
  }
}

class RestaurantList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Restaurant> restaurants1 =
        Provider.of<Restaurants>(context).getRestaurants1;
    print('List: ${restaurants1[0].name}');
    
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) =>
          restaurants1[i].isAvailable || restaurants1[i].totalQuantity != 0
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: restaurants1[i], child: RestaurantCard()),
                    Divider(),
                  ],
                )
              : Container(),
      itemCount: restaurants1.length,
    );
  }
```

The data (**restaurants1**) inside the '**RestaurantList**' widget is being accessed before it is available. Even putting '**await**' while fetching it in **didChangeDependencies** doesn't seem to work.

This is the output I am getting:

> flutter: First stat
>
> flutter: null
>
> flutter: SUCCESS :KFC
>
> flutter: test
>
> [VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread
> information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

**null** is called by the getter 'getRestaurants1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder` widget and retrieve data inside it's `future` parameter. [Official Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) has simple example that describe how to declare and work with `FutureBuilder`.

In your case, try something like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Restaurant>>(
  future: Provider.of<Restaurants>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetRestaurants(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // Items are not available and you need to handle this situation, simple solution is to show a progress indicator
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) =>
          restaurants1[i].isAvailable || restaurants1[i].totalQuantity != 0
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: restaurants1[i], child: RestaurantCard()),
                    Divider(),
                  ],
                )
              : Container(),
      itemCount: restaurants1.length,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you so much :)